# Laravel Auth Bearer Token Expiring

Tags: laravel, authentication

How do I prevent an authed users access token from expiring, I have looked online and changed `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120)` and set this to `SESSION_LIFETIME=35791394` in my `.env` file but the user is still being logged out.

I am using laravel as a backend and react as a frontend. The user logs in on the react web app which sends an API request which returns the access token once the user has logged in.

The issue I am having is after an hour or 2 the access token must be expiring because I keep getting unauthenticated errors when I make API requests. If I log out and back in the access token is refreshed and everything works fine.

Comment: Its the JWT that expires. See [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

Comment: What do you use to authenticate? oAuth,Sanctum?